# If $\Omega$ is a bounded open set and $u$ is harmonic function in $\Omega$ with $u=0$ on the boundary $\partial\Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

If $\Omega$ is a bounded open set and $u$ is harmonic function in $\Omega$ with $u=0$ on the boundary $\partial\Omega$, then $u=0$ inside $\Omega$ as well. Show that boundedness is required for this theorem to be true by using counterexample on the upper half-plane.

I can't think of a nice funtion that will do the job.

Comment: This question is missing the theorem. It seems you've written down the hypothesis, but not the conclusion.

Comment: The post doesn't have a theorem.

Comment: I just edited it.

Comment: If $u$ is harmonic in $\Omega$ then why should we believe $u$ is defined anywhere on $\partial \Omega?$

Comment: The precondition "with $u=0$ on the _boundary_" requires a boundary. Without the boundary the theorem doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $u(x,y)=y$? Then $u$ is harmonic (obviously) and $u(x,0)=0$, so $u$ is zero on the boundary of the upper half-plane (i.e. the line $y=0$).

Answer (score 0):

The theorem follows from the maximum principle.

For the counterexample, consider a degree one polynomial.

Comment: What theorem? What are the hypotheses?

Comment: @zhw. The one in the question: ''If $\Omega$ is a bounded open set and $u$ is harmonic function in $\Omega$ with $u=0$ on the boundary $\partial\Omega$, then $u=0$ inside $\Omega$ as well.''

Comment: Those aren't clear hypotheses. What if $u=1$ on $\Omega$ and $u= 0$ on $\partial \Omega?$

Comment: @zhw. I think it's safe to assume from the context that $u$ is continuous in the closure of $\Omega$. But if we're being nitpicky, yes, you are correct.

Comment: There is no context except what is written. Nitpicky? No, not at all. An important hypothesis is missing.

Comment: There is always context.